# Automatically create users from http header

Tags: plugin-development, users

Bit of an awkward one.

The client wants a system where they send us a link e.g. mycraftsite.com?userid=abc123 and from there we need to populate the user table.

I am new to craft but I am assuming the correct way is to use a plugin, grab the header data and somehow insert it using a hook, but I don't see any available for before the site renders.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are the passing in the username and email through the link?  How is the password supposed to get set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would most likely want to add a [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#how-controller-actions-fit-into-routing) to your custom plugin, with an 'action' method designed to handle the url request and generate a user; using 'post' or 'get' to pass parameters to the controller action.

In the controller action, you can access your parameters using:

```
$username = craft()->request->getParam('username');
```

You can then populate a new User Model using the passed params and save the model.

```
$user = new UserModel();

$user->username   = $username;
$user->email      = $email;
$user->firstName  = $firstName;
$user->lastName   = $lastName;
$user->getContent()->setAttributes([ 
    'customField' => $customFieldValue
]);

craft()->users->saveUser($user);

// We now have a user Id, so assign user to a group
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, $groupId);

// or to multiple groups
//craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, [$groupId, $otherGroupId]);
```

However, by default, controller actions are only accessible to logged-in users. If you want to allow anonymous access you would need to specifically allow it using the [$allowAnonymous property](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions). This definitely introduces some security issues however, so proceed with caution. For example: definitely do not just assign user group(s) blindly from passed parameters or someone might be able to give themselves admin access!

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! can you recommend the best way of hooking it in? The client will provide this link to be used on initial site load, so I need to hook it in before the site renders initially.

Comment: It will be enabled as soon as you activate your plugin — so create plugin; place in plugins folder; goto to plugin settings, install and activate. Check out the [plugin docs](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) for more info on setting up, installing plugins, etc and/or start with a plugin template like the [BusinessLogic Template](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) plugin.